# Not able to delete the Rewrite Rule Set from Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-application-gateway

I am trying to delete the Rewrite Rule Set using AZ CLI and PowerShell but getting the below error. I tried creating the Rewrite Rule Set again and tried removing all the rules but when I am trying to delete it it is not working. Please help.

##[error]Resource /subscriptions/XXXX/resourceGroups/XXXX/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/XXXX/rewriteRuleSets/CacheRuleSet referenced by resource /subscriptions/XXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/XXXXX/requestRoutingRules/BasicRoutingRule was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists, and that both resources are in the same region.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you are using below cmdlet to ***Delete a rewrite rule set***

```
az network application-gateway rewrite-rule set delete --gateway-name --ids --name --no-wait --resource-group
```

> Resource/subscriptions/XXXX/resourceGroups/XXXX/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/XXXX/rewriteRuleSets/CacheRuleSetreferencedbyresource/subscriptions/XXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/XXXXX/requestRoutingRules/BasicRoutingRule was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists, and that both resources are in the same region.

The error usually occur imbalance between resources in various locations. Verify the locations of the resources to make sure they are in the same area.

- Make sure to ***leave the routing rule in place*** before deleting the rule set if the error message *"routing rule not found*" appears.

You can also make use   **`--debug`** command to view complete display of debug logs which might give you a pointer why the error is occurring.

***Reference:***

[az network application-gateway rewrite-rule set | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/application-gateway/rewrite-rule/set?view=azure-cli-latest)

Comment: Thanks Imran. I did a rewrite-rule show but it does not show any region information. Also while creating the rule set I dont think I have used any region. And I have used the command which you have mentioned.

Comment: Can you please post the output after running the comment

Comment: azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (InvalidResourceReference) Resource /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/xxxxxxxxx/rewriteRuleSets/CacheRuleSet referenced by resource /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/xxxxxxxxx/requestRoutingRules/BasicRoutingRule was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists, and that both resources are in the same region.

Comment: 2022-08-01T07:59:39.8049743Z Code: InvalidResourceReference

Comment: Message: Resource /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/xxxxxxxxx/rewriteRuleSets/CacheRuleSet referenced by resource /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/xxxxxxxxx/requestRoutingRules/BasicRoutingRule was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists, and that both resources are in the same region.